# what is wrong in the array map iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, nested

The Below code, not returning a flat array, is highly confusing, Need a flat array of deeply nested array of objects

have attached jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/k6swuvox/

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'XYZ 1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'XYZ 2',
  children: [{
    id: 5,
    name: 'XYZ 5'
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'XYZ 6',
    age: 29,
    children: [{
      id: 7,
      name: 'XYZ 7'
    }, {
      id: 8,
      name: 'XYZ 8'
    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'XYZ 3'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'XYZ 4'
}]


const flats = data => data.map(e => {
  if (e.children) {
    return [...flats(e.children), e]
  } else {
    console.log("E", e);
    return e
  }
})

console.log(flats(arr));
```

Comment: Just calling `flats(arr).flat()` is sufficient in your code.

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, you will sometimes return an array from the callback:

```
return [...flats(e.children),e]
```

and you'll sometimes return a plain object:

```
else {console.log("E",e);return e }
```

so the result will be a mix of arrays and plain objects, instead of an array of only objects.

Use `flatMap` instead, which will implement the flattening you're looking for for you. You'll also need to remove the `.children` property from items with children before returning them.

```js
const arr=[{id:1,name:"XYZ 1"},{id:2,name:"XYZ 2",children:[{id:5,name:"XYZ 5"},{id:6,name:"XYZ 6",age:29,children:[{id:7,name:"XYZ 7"},{id:8,name:"XYZ 8"}]}]},{id:3,name:"XYZ 3"},{id:4,name:"XYZ 4"}];

const flats = data => data.flatMap(e=>{
  const { children, ...objWithoutChildren } = e;
  return children
    ? [...flats(children), objWithoutChildren]
    : e;
});

console.log(flats(arr));
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'XYZ 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'XYZ 2', children: [{ id: 5, name: 'XYZ 5' }, { id: 6, name: 'XYZ 6', age: 29, children: [{ id: 7, name: 'XYZ 7' }, { id: 8, name: 'XYZ 8' }] }] }, { id: 3, name: 'XYZ 3' }, { id: 4, name: 'XYZ 4' }];

const flatten = objectScan(['**(^children$).id'], {
  useArraySelector: false,
  rtn: 'parent',
  reverse: false,
  afterFn: (state) => {
    state.result = state.result.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }));
  }
});

console.log(flatten(arr));
// => [ { id: 1, name: 'XYZ 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'XYZ 2' }, { id: 5, name: 'XYZ 5' }, { id: 6, name: 'XYZ 6' }, { id: 7, name: 'XYZ 7' }, { id: 8, name: 'XYZ 8' }, { id: 3, name: 'XYZ 3' }, { id: 4, name: 'XYZ 4' } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

> Need a flat array of deeply nested array of objects

In that case, I'd prefer `recursive` to get the *flexible and high deep level array.*

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:'XYZ 1'},{id:2,name:'XYZ 2',children:[{id:5,name:'XYZ 5'},{id:6,name:'XYZ 6',age:29,children:[{id:7,name:'XYZ 7'},{id:8,name:'XYZ 8'}]}]},{id:3,name:'XYZ 3'},{id:4,name:'XYZ 4'}];

const recursive = (array) => array.reduce((acc, {children = [], ...others}) => {
  acc.push(others);
  if(children.length > 0) // Base recurisve here.
    acc = acc.concat(recursive(children));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(recursive(arr));
```

*==>* As a result, the content structure will make sure like this
[image]

Comment: Yes. You can accept my answer by clicking the tick to help the reader in the future @yaayhai https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work